# Walking man along hypotenuse

Tags: pstricks

I want to draw a man walking along hypotenuse. How can I fix following code so that it make sense. Problem is that the man is not standing correct.

1) The man should stand correct at point (0,3.5) correct so he is looking at leg from (0,0) to (3,3)

2) When the man is moving along hypotenuse and reaches at (3,0), he should look at the leg from (0,0) to (0,3.5).

I want to introduce the concept of hypotenuse, adjacent and opposite. Therefore I want to make something which makes sense for students.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{pstricks-add}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add    
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}    
\usepackage{pst-fun}

\def\block{%
%  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,90][$y$,90]%
%  \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)%
  %  \rput{*0}(0,0){\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(0,-1.2)\uput[-90](0,-1.2){$\vec{w}$}}%
}


\begin{document}

\multido{\n=.0+.1}{15}{%

\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-1,0)(8,9)
  \pspolygon(0,3.5)(0,0)(3,0)
    \pcline[linestyle=none,offset=0](0,5)(8,0)\naput[labelsep=-\pslinewidth,nrot=:U,npos=\n]{\rput(2,0){\psBill}}

\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fun}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}    

\multido{\rA=.0+.1,\iA=0+1}{10}{%
 \begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-1,-1)(8,7)
 \pspolygon(0,3.5)(0,0)(3,0)
 \pcline[linestyle=none,offset=0](0,3.5)(3,0)
 \ifnum\iA=0 \rput(0,5.5){\psBill}  
 \else
  \ifnum\iA<9
    \naput[labelsep=2,npos=\rA,nrot=:U]{\psBill}    
  \else 
    \naput[labelsep=2,npos=\rA]{\psscalebox{-1 1}{\psBill}} 
  \fi\fi
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I include this in a beamer.

Comment: I cannot figure out how can I change the code so the person is walking from  (3.5,0) to (0,3). I tried different things nothing is working.

Comment: use `\multido{\rA=1+-0.1,\iA=10+-1}{10}{...`